Flexbox Layout Issue - Items Not Displaying Correctly in Rows
I am working on a layout using HTML and CSS with Flexbox. My goal is to display 4 items in each row. However, my current code only displays 3 items per row. I would appreciate any guidance on how to fix this issue.
Despite setting the .element width to 25%, which should allow for 4 items per row, the items are displaying as 3 per row.
Why are the items not displaying 4 per row as expected? How can I adjust my CSS to ensure 4 items per row?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
  border: 4px solid gray;
}

.element {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: silver;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>




"Despite setting the .element width to 25%, which should allow for 4 items per row" - You didn't account for the gap: 8px...

In Flexbox gap is not accounted for when setting widths so you have to adjust the widths to take the gaps into account.
There will be 3 gaps so we have to divide the extra 3 gaps by the 4 items in the row.


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
  border: 4px solid gray;
}

.element {
  width: calc(25% - (8px * (3 / 4)));
  height: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: silver;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>



